# How to start an Activity in onClick method from ArrayAdapter with custom rows

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

So I wrote a custom `ArrayAdapter` to have a `ListView` populate with custom row data, and also to set the `OnClickListener` to each row. I'm facing two major problems here:

1. the specified Activity (`InvoiceActivity`) does not start up on click.
2. The reaction time on clicks when I only output the logmessage (and comment the intent and startActivity part) is really slow.

For now there are only 3 rows of dummy data in the ListView.
I would be grateful for any help here, thanks!

```
public class InvoiceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InvoiceShort> {

public InvoiceListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<InvoiceShort> invoices) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_elem, invoices);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final InvoiceShort invoice = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_elem, parent, false);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View parent) {

                Log.d("item click", "invoice id: " + invoice.getId());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), InvoiceActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", invoice.getId());
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    TextView total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTotal);
    CheckBox paid = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxPaid);

    // populate data
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    date.setText(formatter.format(invoice.getDate()));
    total.setText("€ " + new Long(invoice.getTotal()).toString());
    paid.setChecked(invoice.isPaid());

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here is the xml for one row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxPaid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:checked="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:inputType="none" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="2017-12-30" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textTotal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:text="10€"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please add your layout xml as well for further investigation

Comment: Here you go @FerozSiddiqui

Comment: can you check listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }); is working or not in main activity

Comment: No, I moved from implementing it that way to setting the listener for each row, because before I could not click the rows, but only the views inside. (Even though i set it not to be focusable and have input type none)

Comment: problem here is edit text is getting focused some how or ur convertview click focus is low.     add this in listview tag android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"

Comment: I think you may be on the right track but that did not seem to do anything :/

Comment: can u do one last thing, add the id in linearlayout in ur item.xml and fetch the same in ur custom array adapter from convertview.findViewById write this below the if condition

Comment: @FerozSiddiqui I am not sure if I understood: I added this below the if `View list_elem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_elem);` (and of course added the id to the linear layout)

Comment: LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.yourlayoutid); add this line above 
    TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
 and then set onclick listener ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //write ur logic here })

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution, problem here is you have edittext in your xml but your fetching it as Textview, you can change textview to edittext in list_elem layout your click listener will work . Otherwise you can change textview to edittext in your customAdapter and set two click listener for edittext as below to make it work

```
date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                parent.performClick();
            }
        });
        total.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parent = (View) v.getParent();
                parent.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your constructor like this:-

```
Context mContext;
    public InvoiceListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<InvoiceShort>    
     invoices) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_elem, invoices);
    mContext = context;
   }
```

and use mContext instead of getContext();
this part:-

```
  @Override
        public void onClick(View parent) {

            Log.d("item click", "invoice id: " + invoice.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), InvoiceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", invoice.getId());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
```

try by writing the onclick listner outside the

> if else

```
       convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View parent) {

            Log.d("item click", "invoice id: " + invoice.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), InvoiceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", invoice.getId());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });`
```

Comment: please try to put onclick listener code outside the if else loop.

Comment: Still the same problems @Nikhil Jadhav

Comment: please remove the final from onclick method

Comment: are you able to see any data

Answer (score 0):

Start activity using view context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(convertView.getContext(), InvoiceActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", invoice.getId());
convertView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnClickListener in your Activity class in which you are setting the Adapter and showing the ListView.

Comment: This `OnClickListener` is not for the `ListView` but for each of the Rows. When I implement it in a similar way but as an `OnItemClickListener` for the `Adapter`, I do not get the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the [solution](http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/), in short it is setting this listener to all the views inside one row of the ListView:

```
    /** A definition of a listener that does nothing but to let the click be handled by the parent **/
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    };

    date.setOnClickListener(listener);
    total.setOnClickListener(listener);
    paid.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

And also to implement the `OnItemClickedListener` for the ListView inside the MainActivity